# Add predefined from email address on HTML mailto

Tags: javascript, php, html, mailto

Is there are any way to add predefined from email address on html mailto syntax. So Microsoft Outlook open with a redefined from email address. Any way to do it with php/javascript or anything else.

Comment: You really can't rely on the email agent paying attention to much beyond the implicit "To:" address from a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The references RFC is: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068

You can't set the FROM value but you can do something like this:

```
<a href="mailto:your@email.address?cc=jose@email.address&bcc=john@email.address&subject=Comments about the color blue&body=The following is everything I have to say about the color blue.">Contact Us</a>
```